# How can I use my `.gitignore` to ignore any file that is named like this: "*.tmp.*"?

Tags: git, gitignore

How can I use my `.gitignore` to ignore any file that is named like this: `*.tmp.*`?
For example i have a file called `image.tmp.jpg`, can I be able to mark this without typing the name every time in the gitignore file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add those lines to a `.gitignore` file at the root of your repository:

```
*.tmp.*
**/*.tmp.*
```